A hot poem, hard to hold; not a poem, for those not bold
Can't eat it near
A cup of coffee
Only the skilled may dare to hold
A misspell and a number*
Amounts of paper ruined
Tshirts wet
Was it worth
The particles that rained?
What is it?

 *:The number is not in english, the misspell however; is.

